# Spark Streaming appends to S3 as Parquet format, too many small partitions

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, streaming, parquet

I am building an app that uses Spark Streaming to receive data from Kinesis streams on AWS EMR. One of the goals is to persist the data into S3 (EMRFS), and for this I am using a 2 minutes non-overlapping window.

My approaches:

Kinesis Stream -> Spark Streaming with batch duration about 60 seconds, using a non-overlapping window of 120s, save the streamed data into S3 as:

```
val rdd1 = kinesisStream.map( rdd => /* decode the data */)
rdd1.window(Seconds(120), Seconds(120).foreachRDD { rdd =>
        val spark = SparkSession...
        import spark.implicits._
        // convert rdd to df
        val df = rdd.toDF(columnNames: _*)
        df.write.parquet("s3://bucket/20161211.parquet")
}
```

Here is what s3://bucket/20161211.parquet looks like after a while:
[image: Spark Streaming S3 Parquet]

As you can see, lots of fragmented small partitions (which is horrendous for read performance)...the question is, is there any way to control the number of small partitions as I stream data into this S3 parquet file?

Thanks

What I am thinking to do, is to each day do something like this:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket/20161211.parquet")
df.coalesce(4).write.parquet("s3://bucket/20161211_4parition.parquet")
```

where I kind of repartition the dataframe to 4 partitions and save them back....

It works, I feel that doing this every day is not elegant solution...

Comment: Do you have a flat data schema? Or how do you make sure the schema for every parquet file stays the same?

Comment: @V.Samma Spark DF parquet read has an option "mergeSchema" (default is false), can help you manage evolving schema?

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't handle the case when same column has different types. For example, a column should be double type and one data rows has a value of "2.0" and other has "0". I don't know how it works with Spark streaming, but when Spark's `read.json` reads a file where all the values in this column are "0", then it infers its type as long not double and after writing to parquet, mergeSchema throws an exception because it doesn't know how to handle this case.

Comment: @V.Samma Indeed the same column names with different types fail to merge. I cannot think of a good way to handle this. What I have in mind is not to alter the type directly once your system stablizes, instead add a new column with the different type instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually pretty close to what you want to do, each partition will get written out as an individual file in Spark. However `coalesce` is a bit confusing since it can (effectively) apply upstream of where the coalesce is called. The warning from the Scala doc is:

> ```
> However, if you're doing a drastic coalesce, e.g. to numPartitions = 1,
> this may result in your computation taking place on fewer nodes than
> you like (e.g. one node in the case of numPartitions = 1). To avoid this,
> you can pass shuffle = true. This will add a shuffle step, but means the
> current upstream partitions will be executed in parallel (per whatever
> the current partitioning is).
> ```

In Dataset's its a bit easier to `persist` and `count` to do wide evaluation since the default `coalesce` function doesn't take `repartition` as a flag for input (although you could construct an instance of `Repartition` manually).

Another option is to have a second periodic batch job (or even a second streaming job) that cleans up/merges the results, but this can be a bit complicated as it introduces a second moving part to keep track of.

Comment: Thanks Holden for answering! I like the option of having a second scheduled batch job, it just feels cleaner to do so. We have a scheduler service, so this should be manageable.