# Persisting Kinesis messages to S3 in Parquet format

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-kinesis

I have Kinesis stream to which my app writes ~10K messages per second, in proto format.

I would like to persist those messages to S3 in parquet format. For easy search afterwards, I need to partition my data by User ID field, which is part of the message.

Currently, I have a lambda function that is triggered by Kinesis event. It receives up to 10K of messages, group them by User ID, and then write those files to S3 in parquet format.

My problem is that the files this lambda function generates are very small, ~200KB, while I would like to create ~200MB files for better query performance (I query those files using AWS Athena).

Naive approach would be to write another lambda function that read those files and merge them (rollup) into a big file, but I feel like I'm missing something and there must be a better way of doing it.

I'm wondering if I should use Spark as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155465/spark-streaming-appends-to-s3-as-parquet-format-too-many-small-partitions) question.

Comment: Please be careful when reviewing suggested edits. You recently approved [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23276102), which has zero improvement and, per the comment, was solely to test editing.

Comment: @jhpratt, ok, but how is your comment related to this thread?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use two additional services from AWS:

**AWS Kinesis Data Analytics** to consume data from Kinesis Stream and generate SQL analysis over your data (group, filter, etc). See more here: https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-analytics/

**AWS Kinesis Firehose** plugged after Kinesis Data Analytics. With this service, we can create a parquet file on s3 at every X minutes or every Y MB with arrived data. See more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html

A second way to do it is by using Spark Structured Streaming. So you could read from AWS Kinesis Stream, filter not usable data and export to s3 as described here:
https://databricks.com/blog/2017/08/09/apache-sparks-structured-streaming-with-amazon-kinesis-on-databricks.html

P.S.: This example show how to output into a local filesystem, but you can change it to s3 location.

Comment: Thanks. As to Kinesis Firehouse, I don't think I can partition the data using it. From what I understand, it will read all messages and write them in one file, while I need to group them by User ID.

Comment: Kinesis firehose can consume your data from Kinesis stream and output parquet files at every X minutes or every Y MB (it can generate many files). Is the group by ID really important to you? If the answer is yes, you  must use Spark Structured Stream.

Comment: Updating answer with cloud solution using AWS Kinesis data analytics